# NSFetchRequest that retrieves only the desired attribute of all entities

Tags: core-data, swift, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Is there a way to do a fetch that only returns a list of all the values a specific attribute in a group of entities.

For example, I have a bunch of `User` entities and they all have an attribute `userId`. Is there a way to perform a fetch to get all the userIds without having to fetch everything for every user?

I do not know of a way of doing this with a predicate since usually it is used to match attributes that have a specific value (or at least this is how I use it). For example `NSPredicate("id = %@),String(a_id))`. Which isn't useful for me in this situation. I also tried using something like `request.propertiesToFetch = ["id","lastActivityAt"]` in an attempt to do this but with two attributes. However this still resulted in me getting every attribute for the students.

Any ideas? I'm doing this in hopes of quicker fetches.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `propertiesToFetch`, you also need to use the dictionary result type. That should do you, though it might not make your fetch quicker.

Comment: How could it not make my fetch quicker?

Comment: I said it might not. I don't know how core data works under the hood, why _would_ it make the fetch quicker? You'd have to test it.